# Proxy with terminal

Tags: internet, proxy, virtualbox-networking

I've set a global proxy from Applications -> Network so firefox has access.

I've followed ['apt-get' does not work with Proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy) so apt-get also works.

But if I try other commands which require the internet, for example wget, I generally get errors to the effect of:

> failed: Connection timed out.

How can I set EVERYTHING to use the proxy? There's no other way to connect.

Tried `bash -c export http_proxy='proxy_ip:port/'` from [no internet for terminal- connect through a proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308809/no-internet-for-terminal-connect-through-a-proxy?rq=1) but no joy.

Comment: You could try the easy to use GUI tool [GrrProxy](https://github.com/Cadogan/GrrProxy)

Answer (score 0):

`bash -c` will not set http_proxy in your current environment.

(btw no need to export it in the environment)

Set it manually at the terminal prompt

```
$ http_proxy=http://server:port
$ wget ...
```

If you want to have it enabled each time you open a terminal, edit your .bashrc file  (located in the root of your home directory) and add the line at the end of the file :

```
$ gedit $HOME/.bashrc
 ...
 http_proxy=http://server:port
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always edited the wgetrc file to use wget from behind a proxy. There are two wgetrc files. First of all there is /etc/wgetrc for global configuration and secondly there is ~/.wgetrc for user based configuration.

If you add the following line into wgetrc you can configure it to use a proxy:

```
http_proxy=http://server:port
```

Hope this helps.