# Can't detect internet connection in terminal and Ubuntu software center

Tags: command-line, software-center, internet, 15.10

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10. I can connect to the internet in mozilla. However, the terminal and Ubuntu software center don't detect the internet connection. What can I do?

Comment: Please post the output of `ping -c 3 8.8.8.8` and `ping -c 3 fb.com` and `route -n`

Comment: How are you accessing the internet? Do you have a proxy?

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus No output for ping -c 3 8.8.8.8 . When I stopped the process, 3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2016ms. 
Same for the second one
route -n:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.42.11.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp19s0
10.42.11.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp19s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp19s0

Comment: @TshilidziMudau Ethernet. I think I entered the proxy setting in mozilla. But apart from that, just IP address, Net mask, gateway etc. in the connection settings in Ubuntu.

Comment: What about `ping -c 3 10.42.11.1`. And what are the proxy settings you entered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no internet for terminal- connect through a proxy](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308809/no-internet-for-terminal-connect-through-a-proxy)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are connecting to a  proxy, you need to do the following:

Create the following file : `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Edit this file according to your proxy details:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

If your proxy doesn’t require a username, then those statements take the following form: `Acquire::http::proxy yourproxyaddress:proxyport";`

To be able to add what is a PPA, you will need to export your proxy settings open the terminal and type:

```
export https_proxy="https://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";

export http_proxy="http://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

Once you have done this, to export you will need to add a `-E` after `sudo`, e.g. `sudo -E apt-get install python-software-properties`