# Not able to ping google and cannot get apt-get update

Tags: networking, apt, internet

I have set my network to NAT because this is my home internet that I am using. I am not able to access my college internet to get the `apt-get update` package hence using home internet. Below is my setting for `vim /etc/netowrk/interfaces`

[image]

I try the `apt-get update` to install the packages and I get the following error;

[image]

I am also not able to ping google.com. I have tried everything and its not working

Comment: Try this command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolveconf`

Comment: Please include the content of `/etc/network/interfaces` as text, not as an image

Comment: Am I right to assume that your college has a proxy in place? if so, then you may find this answer  here:  http://askubuntu.com/a/708155/476968 to be useful.

Comment: I would prefer more in detail as the statements above confuses a bit. What do you mean by **I have set my network to NAT**, which is usually done by the device (a router basically) does that anyways. Do you not have DHCP enabled on the whatever the device you're connected to? How does it differentiate between college and home internet..? Please add more in details to further advise.